# Bar button item not showing

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

The navigation bar button is not showing in my project. I have created this demo project below to illustrate it. As you can see, the right bar button item is only showing on the greyVC and not the yellowVC. I might be able to add it programatically but that would be my last resort. I want to figure out why it is not showing with this storyboard way.

[image: barButtonNotShowing]

Comment: Go to the navigation controller and uncheck the "showNavigation bar", then you can see bar button added by you. Let me know if it does not work out

Comment: I did that and unchecking "showNavigation bar" just makes all navigation bar disappear. Are you suggesting making my own navigation bar in all VC including back button etc?

Comment: Yes, I think you have to do that, because the structure you have shown in your story board, represents navigation bar's root controller is tab bar controller, which quite awkward.

Comment: I couldnt have done it another way because of this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39070159/present-view-controller-over-current-tabbarcontroller-with-navigationcontroller

Comment: There, he is saying to embed the navigation controller to View controller, then connect tab bar controller  from that viewController, but in your case you have taken tab bar as your root controller. Am I correct?

Comment: Hi @Janmenjaya, no, in both cases it is NavVC (RootVC)-> TabVC-> Normal VC. I am actually the question raiser from that post. Fixing up some stuff after the change. Cheers

Comment: Did you try adding that by code?

Comment: I did and it works. However, it creates all sort of problem when changing VC. If I put it in viewWillAppear, it does not get triggered properly when I dismiss to the currentVC. That is why I am hoping storyboard would work

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:[image]

And i Got the Bar button In Both the screens..[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please take a look at the above comment that links to the other question from SO. There is a very specific reason why I couldn't do it like that. Cheers