# Present a viewcontroller from a UITabbarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Instagram has the following UITabbarController: [image]

It has a special behavior which I couldn't duplicate. Every TabbarItem behaves like every other one but the center one doesn't show simply a viewcontroller but presents one instead. I would like to know how to do that.

I was thinking that they use a Toolbar with custom buttons but I feel like it's a bad practice. On every tab we have to allocate the view controllers. This behavior unfortunately resets the state of the view controller after a switch to another controller.

I would love to get a solution where I can use a `UITabbarController` but present one of the view controllers.

Comment: Did you tried this?

[self.tabBarController presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: That's the point, how can I set a own event to the tab bar item? As far as I know it's connected to the viewcontroller. The only solution would be to create a dummy view controller which only presents that.

Comment: Yes, you would need a dummy view controller to achieve it.

Comment: Please have a look onto this http://stackoverflow.com/a/39389549/1922188